# Manipulating Taylor Series for $e^{2x}$ using $e^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I’m a calculus student learning infinite series and sequences for the first time, and I have a question about manipulating the Taylor series for $e^x$ to arrive at one for $e^{2x}$.

My first thought was to say that 
$$g(x) = e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
And $f(x) = x^2$, so 
$$
e^{2x}
 = g(f(x))
 = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(n!)^2}
$$
However, this isn’t what my textbook got. It said that I can just set $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = 2x$, meaning that $$f(g(x)) = e^{2x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}$$
I understand this and think it’s a little simpler than what I originally tried out.

So both of these methods make sense to me, but I got different answers for each of them. What am I doing wrong in the first one?

Comment: It is true that when you expand the product $(e^x)^2 = (1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3! + \ldots)^2$ then you will arrive at the power-series of $e^{2x}$. You probably didn't compute it correctly. Note how much easier the second method is compare to this one (you need to compute the product of two infinite series). To compute the product of two power-series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n \cdot \sum_{n\geq 0} b_n x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n x^n$ see [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!!

Comment: @ElizabethBecker i updated my answer to write out the correct multiplication logic

Comment: Freshman's dream $(a+b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2.$  You need those cross terms.  ($\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n)(\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_{n-k}b_k x^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
e^y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}
$$
therefore, if $y=2x$ you get
$$
e^{2x}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^k}{k!}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k x^k}{k!}
$$

---

There are issues with what you did. Even though as you claim
$$
e^{2x}
 = \left(e^x\right)^2
 = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^2,
$$
but squaring that sum is not a simple matter because of the crossing terms, since
$$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy \ne x^2 + y^2$$

---

If you want to continue your method to its logical end, you can use
$$
\begin{split}
e^{2x}
 &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right) 
    \cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}\right) \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} 
    \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n x^n}{n!},
\end{split}
$$
with the last step using the Binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Your step $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(n!)^2}$$
is akin to claiming that
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$$